# Django: How to reuse Custom user model - inherit or extend?

Tags: python, django, inheritance, django-models

I have different apps in my django project. I want to keep an independent app for auth&auth that is reused in all apps. The auth&auth app is one app with my basic custom user model. This user needs to log in with email so I am inheriting from AbstractBaseUser instead of extending the User class. Now in all apps the login is same way, basic user attributes are same; but some apps add additional fields like 'salary', others use the model as is. So what is the best way to reuse the Custom User model I created in my login app? If I inherit the concrete class, I'll have 2 tables. If I declare the Custom User class abstract, how will I use its functionalities, roles and permissions?

Comment: It sounds more like you need to modify the authentication login step than your user models.. is that an option?

Comment: Thanks for responding Sayse, I'll have to say no its not though, since then I'll have to define the user model everywhere, just for one or two extra columns in few places.

Comment: define your user model somewhere and import it everywhere else ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to achieve what you are asking for is:

```
class Learners(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=True)
    nick = models.CharField(max_length=12, unique=True)
    #Many to Many relationship with course
    courses = models.ManyToManyField(Course, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.get_full_name()
```

Where the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` is set to the Custom User model, inheriting from AbstractBaseUser, that you created, like this : `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'courseSystem.MyUser'` in settings.py for the main Django project. In my example `courseSystem.MyUser` is the Custom User Class defined.

I am sharing this from a similar situation you have described above, that I am working on.

In the above example, if you were to make the custom `MyUser` class as abstract and then inherit the `Learners` class from it:

```
class Learners(MyUser):
```

then Learners class would no longer be a `models.Model` type class but the concrete User class for that app, and in each case i.e., for each such class ineheriting from the abstract MyUser class, you would have to overload the necessary members of `MyUser` required for a concrete user class for Django. Also since you are using `AbstractBaseUser` and not extending on default `User` class, you would have to define custom User forms, and User Managers for your custom user class. So if you have a concrete `MyUser` class, as in the example above, you can define the custom User Manager and User Forms for `MyUser` once, and keep one-to-one relationship to it from your models in different apps. But if you make the `MyUser` class as abstract, you wouldn't define User Forms and User Managers for `MyUser`, but separately for each of your apps where you form a concrete user class by inheriting from this abstract Custom User class.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/